# Unbreakable Line Problem

Tags: page-breaking

I have a weird problem with line breaking in my document. On the second-to-last page (last results before the conclusion), I have a large figure in the upper half of the page and three incomplete paragraphs below, split into two columns.  For some reason, I have (1) linebreaks between the paragraphs (which isn't default for this document) (2) a huge amount of empty space above and below the figure, and (3) two orphaned lines on the next page. What's weird is that the linebreaks should be enough to allow the text to not be orphaned.

The format looks a bit like this:

```
 FIGURE ACROSS TWO COLUMNS
incomplete Par1 | End of Par2
\linebreak      | \linebreak
Start of Par2   | Start of Par3

pagebreak

last 2 lines of Par3
\linebreak
\section{Conclusion}
```

I've tried a bunch of things suggested on this forum to fix the problem, but to limited success:

1. parbox, samepage, etc.  Result: P2 and P3 get thrown all on next page, weird chunk of whitespace
2. (As a test) throwing away the paragraph breaks and making P1,P2,P3 all one long paragraph. Result: whitespace at the bottom of the page rises by 1 space, and the widowed lines remain at the top of the next page
3. Adjusting the size of the whitespace under the figure. Result: reasonable, but results in a ragged bottom which looks weird unless I manually adjust it to the perfect amount, which obviously defeats the point of TeX
4. Adjusting the widowpenalty.  This results in the entire document having ragged bottoms, excessive whitespace, and in general looking funny

I've looked through a bunch of the other suggestions, but they haven't worked right. Thanks!

Comment: Could you include all the code that gives you these problems you mention? Very often the solution depends on your specific approach or choice of commands - so if you give it to us to replicate the problem, we can solve it faster for you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: it isn't clear if your code fragment is really trying to show your code or is a schematic for the _output_. Surely you have not got `\linebreak` immediately before `\section` in your source have you? (If you have that would be the source of all kinds of weird breaking effects)

Comment: By linebreaks I assume you mean larger than normal gaps (presumably due to interparagraph glue).  Have you tried using \raggedbottom?  Also, one extra line is an orphan, two lines are not penalized.